# Ideas on keeping persistent WooCommerce cart data inthe header to non-WordPress pages on the same domain

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Our eCommerce is built in WordPress/WooCommerce. The rest of the site is built in Laravel. When a user is on domain.com/shop, for example, adds a product to their cart, and then navigates away from domain.com/shop to domain.com/laravel-page, we’d like to retain the cart icon in the headed with any products they’ve added. Removing products from the header widget isn’t as important and just seeing them with continue to cart/checkout buttons. Any ideas on accomplishing this? I know WooCommerce sets a series of cookies... is this something we could tap into? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it your WordPress and Laravel are on the same domain you can make an ajax call to the WordPress backend to get the cart data.

jQuery to make the ajax call

```
(function ($) {
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $.ajax ({
            url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function (resp) {
                if (resp.success) {
                    // build your cart details
                }
                else {
                    // handle the error
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert ('Request failed: ' + thrownError.message) ;
            },
        }) ;
    }) ;
})(jQuery) ;
```

In your theme `functions.php` file register the ajax call

```
<?php
// if the ajax call will be made from JS executed when user is logged into WP
add_action ('wp_ajax_call_your_function', 'get_woocommerce_cart_data') ;
// if the ajax call will be made from JS executed when no user is logged into WP
add_action ('wp_ajax_nopriv_call_your_function', 'get_woocommerce_cart_data') ;

function get_woocommerce_cart_data () {
    global $woocommerce;
    $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
    // build the output array
    $out = array();
    foreach($items as $item => $values) { 
        // get product details
        $getProductDetail = wc_get_product( $values['product_id'] );
        $out[$item]['img'] = $getProductDetail->get_image();
        $out[$item]['title'] = $getProductDetail->get_title();
        $out[$item]['quantity']  = $values['quantity'];
        $out[$item]['price'] = get_post_meta($values['product_id'] , '_price', true);
    }
    // retun the json
    wp_send_json_success($out);
}
```